# How to decompose a color into percentage of other multiple defined colors

Tags: python, opencv, math, optimization, colors

I have these colors, I can combine these color with a ratio using the code below

[image]

```
avreg =  np.around((red_patch*0.1) + (blue_patch*0.4) + (yellow_patch*0.5)).astype(int)
```

the results are shown below

[image]

is there away to decompose this color into the previous color it was created from. Like finding the ratio of each color that resulted in this color

Answer (score 3):

Let's say `Y` is the np.ndarray representing the resulting color, then you can get the coefficients you're looking for with

```
M = np.column_stack((red_patch, blue_patch, yellow_patch))
print(np.linalg.inv(M)@Y)
```

(Note that coefficients might not be exactly those you typed in because of rounding issues due to `.astype(int)`, but it should roughly do the trick)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to add, for non square matrix this can be used. np.linalg.pinv(M)